# ios permissions in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-permissions

I have a flutter application and it was uploaded to the Google Play Store a while ago and there is no problem now I want to upload it to the iPhone on the Appstore What are the permissions that I must add, the application contains receiving notifications from Firebase messaging and an option to save images to the mobile as well as Google Analytics and a button to share the news I do not want the application to be rejected, so I ask and I hope to help me write what should be added, thank you

my pubspec.yaml file:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.17
 
  rename: ^2.0.1
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  flutter_linkify: ^5.0.2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.21.0
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.3
  
  firebase_analytics: ^9.3.2
  
  
  date_count_down: ^2.1.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.9
  share_plus: ^6.3.0
  
  http: ^0.13.5
 
  
  dio: ^4.0.6
  
  flutterfire_ui: ^0.4.3+7
  path_provider: ^2.0.12
  gallery_saver: ^2.3.2
  flutter_email_sender: ^5.2.0
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
```

Comment: Please share your pubspec.yaml file so that we know which type of package you are using ..otherwise it will be tough to support you.

Comment: pubspec.yaml file is available

Answer (score 0):

**Check this package:**
https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler
In `Setup` section expand **iOS** drop down arrow and it will show you a list of permissions that will help you include all the possible needed permissions